# Javascript replace from to

Tags: javascript, jquery, str-replace

I found good tutorials on how to do a string replace all for a string, but how to replace from a to b ?

Lets say we have this selector

```
$('a.mylink')
```

This selector will return something like

```
<a class=​"micro_avatar my_avatar">​</a>​ 
<a href=​"#!/​users/​user_name" style=​"background:​ 
  url(https:​/​/​secure.gravatar.com/​avatar/​randomnumber?size=24&default=mm)​ 
  no-repeat" class=​"micro_avatar">​</a>​
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_sgu7CioctU
```

In the page that Im testing this, will find multiple ocurrences of this w variations ( imagine a blog and each post have this inside).

Now we want to replace all the ocurrences to look like this

```
<a class=​"micro_avatar my_avatar">​</a>​ 
<a ** rel='nofollow' ** href=​"#!/​users/​user_name" style=​"background:​ 
  url(https:​/​/​secure.gravatar.com/​avatar/​randomnumber?size=24&default=mm)​ 
  no-repeat" class=​"micro_avatar">​</a>​

**<iframe width="560" height="315" src="** http://www.youtube.com/embed/_sgu7CioctU
**" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>**
```

The trick part is not all the youtube links will have the same link.

Comment: _"This will return 4"_ - I don't understand. The numeric value 4 doesn't make sense, four elements doesn't make sense given that the selector `'a.mylink'` won't match the html you've shown. What does `$('a.mylink')` have to do with the rest of your question? Are you saying the first code block is actually the content of a string and you want to change it to look like the second, or is that somewhere in your document's body, or...?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Javascript substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

```
var result = 
    val.substr(a, b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Updated

**HTML**

```
<span class="youtube_url">http://www.youtube.com/embed/_sgu7CioctU</span>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('.micro_avatar:not(.my_avatar)').attr('rel',nofollow);
$('<iframe>', {
   src: $('.youtube_url').text(),
   id:  'myFrame',
   width: 560,
   allowfullscreen: true,
   height:350
}).appendTo('body');
```

Comment: problem here is the youtube Url is not alw the same one, so we have to parse the url id for each case

Comment: You should store the `youtube url` in an element, then you can fetch in `script`. Check the above answer I've made changes in it.